# jquery UI sorting with groups and without groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a Table code which is conditional, one one condition: table structure is like this:

```
<table id="uisortable" data-section="inline" class="table ui-sortable" width="100%" border="0">
    <tbody>

        <tr id="item-8258">
            <td width="3%">1</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8261">
            <td width="3%">2</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8260">
            <td width="3%">3</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8264">
            <td width="3%">4</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8262">
            <td width="3%">5</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8266">
            <td width="3%">6</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8263">
            <td width="3%">7</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8267">
            <td width="3%">8</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8265" style="background-color:#CCC;">
            <td width="3%">9</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8268">
            <td width="3%">10</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8259">
            <td width="3%">11</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8269">
            <td width="3%">12</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8270">
            <td width="3%">13</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8271">
            <td width="3%">14</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8272">
            <td width="3%">15</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8273">
            <td width="3%">16</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8274">
            <td width="3%">17</td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

and on another condition, the structure is like this:

```
<table id="uisortable" data-section="table" class="table ui-sortable" width="100%" border="0">
    <tbody>

        <tr id="item-8535" class="parent sortable-row ui-state-default" data-question-id="1128">
            <td width="3%">2</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8536" class="childrow ui-state-default" data-answer-id="1128">
            <td width="3%">4</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8531" class="childrow ui-state-default" data-answer-id="1129">
            <td width="3%">6</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8534" class="childrow ui-state-default" data-answer-id="1129">
            <td width="3%">8</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8527" class="childrow ui-state-default" data-answer-id="1125">
            <td width="3%">9</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8530" class="parent sortable-row ui-state-default" data-question-id="1125">
            <td width="3%">10</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8532" class="childrow ui-state-default" data-answer-id="1125">
            <td width="3%">11</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8537" class="childrow ui-state-default" data-answer-id="1125">
            <td width="3%">12</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8528" class="parent sortable-row ui-state-default" data-question-id="388">
            <td width="3%">13</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8523" class="parent sortable-row ui-state-default" data-question-id="225">
            <td width="3%">14</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="item-8533" class="parent sortable-row ui-state-default" data-question-id="1127">
            <td width="3%">15</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now i am using jquery UI sortable plug-in to sort, The first is working fine as it does not have any parent child relation, with second, it is messing everything,

I am trying to move parent along with childrens in place of another parent and resort it, the dropable parent can have childrens and they cannot have childrens,

childrens can move inside their parents only

The code is there but is is not working in proper manner, i am definitely missing something, here is my code

```
var $tableToReorder = $("#uisortable");
var isTable = $tableToReorder.data('section');
if (isTable == 'inline') {
    var items = 'tr';
    var handle = false;
    var forceHelperSize = false;
} else {
    var items = 'tr';
    var handle = '.childrow';
    var forceHelperSize = true;
}
var sortableHelper = function(e, ui) {
    ui.children().each(function() {
        $(this).width($(this).width());
    });
    return ui;
};

function SortingStared() {
    $('#uisortable').sortable({
        containment: "document",
        items: items,
        opacity: '.5',
        axis: "y",
        helper: sortableHelper,
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        handle: handle,
        forceHelperSize: forceHelperSize,
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        start: function(e, ui) {
            ui.placeholder.height(ui.helper.outerHeight());
            notice("Sort Order Updating, Please wait...", "info");
        },
        update: function(e, ui) {

            if (isTable == 'inline') {
                $.post('sort.php', order, function() {
                    alert("done");
                });
            } else {
                var tableHasUnsortableRows = $(this).find('> tbody > tr:not(.sortable-row)').length;

                $(this).find('> tbody > tr.sortable-row').each(function(idx, row) {
                    /* If we are reordering a table with some fixed rows, make sure the fixed rows
                     * always follow their corresponding sortable row so they always appear together. */
                    if (tableHasUnsortableRows) {
                        var uniqID = $(this).attr('data-question-id'),
                            correspondingFixedRow = $('tr:not(.sortable-row)[data-answer-id=' + uniqID + ']');
                        correspondingFixedRow.detach().insertAfter($(this));
                    }
                });

                info = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'sort.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: info,
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert("done");
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        activate: function(event, ui) {
            for (var i = $('.ui-state-default').length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                $('.pull-left:eq(' + i + ')').html(i + 1);
            }
        }
    }).disableSelection();
}
```

I am using

```
handle: handle,
forceHelperSize: forceHelperSize,
```

but i am not sure it will work or not, added this and it does not drag

the fiddle which i had pasted is here

> https://jsfiddle.net/3hqs21w6/12/

it is working somewhat but this i have created from the table structure

Comment: `I am trying to move parent along with childrens in place of another parent and resort it, the dropable parent can have childrens and they cannot have childrens,` Can you explain that better? Is there a working example that is similar to what you're trying to do?

Comment: i will try to create a fiddle for this

Comment: here is the fiddle i created, but it seems it not working because of the handle and forcehelpersize i had added https://jsfiddle.net/3hqs21w6/2/